# Errno 13 Permission denied, in WSL, virtualenv, even as root

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux, running Debian, upgraded to Buster. I configured Visual Studio Code with remote development as well. Uninstalled python2.7, and made python3 as my default by creating a symlink `/usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3`.

So, in my home directory, as the current user I create a virtualenv: `python -m virtualenv -p python3 venv`, and all is fine.

I then proceed to activate it. I use fish mostly, but this problem is also when running bash. `source venv/bin/activate.fish`. All is fine, it works.

Then, I try to install my package `python setup.py install`, and it works fine:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing myproj.egg-info/PKG-INFO writing dependency_links to myproj.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
...
```

And then it  proceeds to installing dependencies.

```
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/jmespath/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/94/7179c3832a6d45b266ddb2aac329e101367fbdb11f425f13771d27f225bb/jmespath-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=3720a4b1bd659dd2eecad0666459b9788813e032b83e7ba58578e48254e0a0e6
Best match: jmespath 0.9.4
Processing jmespath-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing jmespath-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl to /home/ap/projects/myproj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ap/projects/myproj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jmespath-0.9.4-py3.7.egg/jmespath-0.9.4.dist-info' -> '/home/ap/projects/myproj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jmespath-0.9.4-py3.7.egg/EGG-INFO'
```

All directories have permissions, I'm the owner, and creating the symlink from the CLI works. I even tried to do this by first elevating permissions with `sudo su`, and still getting "Permission denied".

I tried downgrading pip and setuptools by a major version but it didn't help. I've been doing this on Linux countless times and it all worked fine, I just don't get what might be the cause for this.

`pip list` output:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.2.1
setuptools 41.0.1
wheel      0.33.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this was because the underlying file system is NTFS, and Linux handles open files differently from Windows. Once a file was open, from WSL, apparently there was a lock on it, and it can't be overwritten. So the only thing that worked was to close Visual Studio Code, do the install, upgrade, whatever, then re-open it.

This is a wild hunch, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I was not using VSCode, but experienced a similar error in WSL when building a wheel file (`setup.py bdist_wheel`).  What helped was to copy the source folder to `/tmp` and create the wheel file there.